# how to show multiple fields in a single column editor in extjs grid

Tags: extjs, gridview, editor, cell

We are building an application which is using the grid to show records. Now we cam across with a requirement to show 2 fields(1combo and 1 textfield) in a single cell editor. we have tried with 2columns with 2editors but the problem here is we need to enable the both cell editors at the same time.

this link http://blog.platinastudio.com/?attachment_id=2485 can be helpful for understanding the requirement clearly.

any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks
Sanjeeva

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `we need to enable the both cell editors`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use two columns and 2 editors, then you should just need to do the wiring manually, and it should work okay.

- For each editor, listen for the [beforeedit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit) event
- In the handler, call [startEdit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-method-startEdit) on the other editor

You'll need to configure the editors to not reset on blur probably, and there may be additional configuration needed to get the interactions right, but in theory it should work out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use two editors in the same cell, then you can mention xtype:'container' in the editor configuration of the column and add your fields in this container.

An example of this is given [here](http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/extjs-4-using-multiple-fields-inside-a-row-editor-cell-for-editing-large-values/)